# How to store multiple images paths into database in laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I am working on multiple image upload in laravel. Uploading is successful but, i got an issue. For later use i should store in database. For single column it easy but for different column for different images i couldnot do it.

Here is my image upload code
 $images = [];
        $destDir = "public/uploads/";

```
    if($request->file('image1')) $images[]=$request->file('image1');
    if($request->file('image2')) $images[]=$request->file('image2');
    if($request->file('image3')) $images[]=$request->file('image3');

    foreach($images as $image)
    {

        if(!empty($image))
        {
            $imageName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
            $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $temPath = $image->getRealPath();
            $enImg = mt_rand(1111,9999).".".$extension;
            $newPath = $destDir.$enImg.".".$extension;
            move_uploaded_file($temPath, $newPath);
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling you are approaching this in a way that is making it more difficult for you. Instead of creating multiple separate file inputs in your form you can only set a multiple file input and set the name of the input to an array like so:

```html
<form action="demo_form.asp">
  Images: <input type="file" name="images[]" multiple>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Then in your php you can do something like this:

```php
if (isset($request->all()['images'])) {
    $this->persistUserImages($request->all()['images'], $userId);
}

/**
 * Persists user images to storage and DB
 *
 * @param array $userImages
 * @param int $userId
 * @return array
 */
private function persistUserImages(array $userImages, $userId = 1)
{
    if (empty($userImages)) {
        return [];
    }

    $uploadedUserImagesFilenames = $this->uploadUserImagesToCloud($userImages, $userId);

    foreach ($uploadedUserImagesFilenames as $filename) {
        $userImage = new UserImage([
            'user_id' => $userId,
            'filename' => $filename,
            'visible' => 1
        ]);

        $userImage->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: @pandesantos Did this end up solving your problem?

Comment: @restis-palampougioukis Yes thank you :) . Sorry for being late.

Comment: @pandesantos no problem mate! Glad to be able to help out. Could you mark the answer as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this this. In your blade,

```
<form action="{{url('path')}}" methos="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Images: <input type="file" name="images[]" multiple>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

In you method,

```
 public function store(Request $request){

      foreach ( $request->images as $image) {
            Model::create([
                'image_url' => $image,
            ]);
        }

}
```

Or
follow below link. It's very easy way to solve this problem. 
[Multiple Image Upload In Laravel](https://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-56-multiple-image-upload-using-bootstrap-fileinputexample.html)

Hope you can solved your problem.

Answer (score -1):

create a pivot table and store images in separate rows..

```
Table schema:- `images` table
columns `id`,`user_id`(foreign key),`image_path`
```

store your `$newPath` in this table every time..